# How to encapsulate a request manager in Angular7 using httpClient?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7, angular-httpclient

I'm new to Angular, and I am using the httpClient like this:

```js
 public getFocusAreaDataWithHttpClient() {

    this.http.get(Api.focusAreaApi).subscribe({
      next(response) {
        console.log("httpClient handle data");
        console.dir(response);
      },
      error(err) {
        console.error("Error: " + err);
      },
      complete() {
        console.log("Completed");
      }
    });
  }
```

I want to encapsulate a service (apiManager.service)to provide a public method then other service can use it to fetch data(need to pass apiurl), what I expect is like this:

```
export class ApiManager {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
// define request header , content-Type , auth token ,and some common config here
// and there should be 2 method - get and post

}
```

and other service can use it like:

```
apiManager.get(apiurl,parameters).subscript...
apiManager.post(apiurl,parameters).subscript...
```

but I have no idea for how to encapsulate it , I'm appreciate if anyone can give me some demo to show how to encapsulate a manager class to provide data fetch function.

Comment: Read the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

In Angular this type of activity is done through [services](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4).

If you use the Angular CLI (which you should definitely use), just type `ng generate service api-manager` in the terminal and it will create all the boilerplate for you.